# Having mysql connection timeout issue in joomla virtuemart?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

I have developed category vise search funcionality for virtumart in front side.
It is working fine on our local server but when i uploaded on the server it is giving me mysql connection timeout error. It shows me like below,

```
Attention no standard shopper group set MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT * FROM `sxrth_virtuemart_shoppergroups` WHERE `default` = "2" AND (`virtuemart_vendor_id` = "1" OR `shared` = "1") AND `published`="1"
Attention no standard shopper group set MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT * FROM `sxrth_virtuemart_shoppergroups` WHERE `default` = "2" AND (`virtuemart_vendor_id` = "1" OR `shared` = "1") AND `published`="1"

 No Shop Currency defined! Go to http://www.domain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=user&task=editshop
```

(I already apply currency and List of accepted currencies for virtuemart for this link)

I tried several option like

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 14400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 14400);
```

but that is not work for me.

I also made php.ini file in publc_html folder. It looks like below

```
register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = off
mysql.connect_timeout = 600
mysql.default_socket = 600
expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 600

max_execution_time 600
memory_limit = 360M
```

Still that is not working for me

Which actions should i have to apply to getting solution. 
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Finally It worked for me after doing following things
1)Given Indexing to my all tables which comes in join
2)Created one php.ini in root folder and added following lines

```
mysql.connect_timeout = 600
max_input_time = 600
max_execution_time 600
memory_limit = 360M
mysqli.reconnect = On
```